# vba multiD array to range

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, multidimensional-array

I'm having an issue with writing an 4D Array to a range in Excel.

My Array Looks like this:

```
varArray(0)
- varArray(0)(0) "test01"
- varArray(0)(1) "test02"
- varArray(0)(2) "test03"
- varArray(0)(3) "test04"

varArray(1)
- varArray(1)(0) "test11"
- varArray(1)(1) "test12"
- varArray(1)(2) "test13"
- varArray(1)(3) "test14"
```

There will be more than only 2 "Items" in the Array in the end but for understanding I displayded 2 of them.

I tried it with transpose but I coudl not Access the subitems

```
Range("A" & CellIndex) = Application.Transpose(varArray(0,1))
```

does not work :S

Output should look like this(write in to a range):

```
       A       B      C      D
1    test01 test02 test03 test04
2    test11 test12 test13 test14
```

Can anyone assist me on this?

Comment: "does not work" -- you get an error, eh? What's the error? Can you structure your array differently e.g., `varArray(0,0)`?

Comment: Show us what you have in your code and what the output currently is so that we can help troubleshoot what you've already got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Application.Transpose` twice. This will output to the worksheet in columns A:D

```
Sub CreateArray()
    Dim varArray As Variant
    varArray = Array(Array(1, 2, 3, 4), Array(11, 12, 13, 14))

    For i = 0 To 1
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D1").Offset(i, 0).Value = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(varArray(i)))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This is it! Thanky you very much, the solution works perfect. the Offset was the missing bit

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this:

Option Explicit

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim varArray            As Variant
    Dim lCounter            As Long
    Dim lCounter2           As Long
    Dim rngCell             As Range

    varArray = Array(Array(1, 2, 3, 4), Array(11, 12, 13, 14))
    Set rngCell = Cells(1, 1)

    For lCounter = LBound(varArray) To UBound(varArray)
        For lCounter2 = LBound(varArray(lCounter)) To UBound(varArray(lCounter))

            Debug.Print varArray(lCounter)(lCounter2)

            rngCell = varArray(lCounter)(lCounter2)
            Set rngCell = rngCell.Offset(0, 1)

        Next lCounter2
        Debug.Print "-----------"
        Set rngCell = Cells(rngCell.Row + 1, 1)

    Next lCounter

End Sub
```

The result in the immediate window is this one:

```
 1 
 2 
 3 
 4 
-----------
 11 
 12 
 13 
 14 
-----------
```

From this output, you can easily come to your desired one.

Comment: Hi Vityata, I want to write the Data into a Range. Each Array index shoudl be 1 row so for the 2 ones above it woudl be: item 1 A1:D1 and item 2 A2:D2

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Dim varArray(0 To 1, 0 To 3) As String
    varArray(0, 0) = "test01"
    varArray(0, 1) = "test02"
    varArray(0, 2) = "test03"
    varArray(0, 3) = "test04"
    varArray(1, 0) = "test11"
    varArray(1, 1) = "test12"
    varArray(1, 2) = "test13"
    varArray(1, 3) = "test14"
Range("A1:D2") = varArray()
Range("F1:G4") = Application.Transpose(varArray())
```

I think the output you want is simply your array, not your transposed array. However I put the two outputs on the code. Feel free to change the adresses...

Comment: I think this array has a different structure to that of OPs. OP has a 1d array containing arrays, rather than a simple 2d array

Comment: Yes. This is not an array of arrays... If you want to transpose it you have to use the operator twice (one inside another)... That's why I suggest this simpler way...

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to transpose a *single* item in the array:

```
Application.Transpose(varArray(0,1))
```

Also, this array isn't indexed in such a manner. You could have `varArray(0)(1)`, but you *don't* have `varArray(0,1)`.

Try this:

```
Dim x as Long
For x = LBound(varArray) To UBound(varArray)
    Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(varArray(x)) + 1).Offset(x) = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(varArray(x)))

Next
```